# Proof: Graph Coloring algorithm needs at most twice as many colors to color a graph as the optimal solution

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing, coloring

Given an algorithm

(1) create the complement $\bar{G}$ of input graph $G$

(2) calculate a maximum matching $M$ on $\bar{G}$

(3) color the two vertices of every edge $e_i \in M$ with color $i$

(4) color remaining nodes on the original graph with a greedy approach (every vertices receives the smallest color possible)

Proof that this algorithm needs at most twice as many colors as $\chi(G)$.

*Edit: $G$ requires to have at least one edge such that $\chi(G) \geq 2$.*

Can someone give me a hint how to start this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it doesn't. In particular, if $G = \overline{K_n}$, then this uses $\frac n2$ colors where one color would do.

Comment: You are right, sounds reasonable.
One thing I missed though is, that we said in the lecture that we only look at $G$ with at least one edge to avoid such edge-cases.

Comment: My objection still stands for cases like that. It's easy to construct many examples of bipartite graphs $G$ such that $\overline{G}$ has a perfect matching: using $\frac n2$ rather than $2$ colors.

Comment: Do you mind giving  me an example?

Comment: Are you telling me that you've tried an example and it *didn't* have this property?